# Meaning of "по ходу"

Tags: словоупотребление

I've recently come across this expression in two sentences and the dictionaries are no help:

> Слышь, сегодня лучше не попадайся на глаза шефу: он, **по ходу**,
>   озверел из-за чего-то там.

---

> **По ходу**, нас кинули!

Comment: I believe it's *нас кинули* which means "we've been ripped off"

Comment: YES! that was a typo :)

Comment: По ходу - briefly, is "by the way" in slang.

Comment: *"Походу"* в этих предложениях должно писаться слитно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Источник?

Comment: @NikolayErshov 1. [викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83) 2. ниже есть заплюсованный ответ, где говорится, что "походу" - синоним "похоже", а "похоже" пишется слитно. 3. это слово не зависит от других - а потому предлога перед ним стоять не может.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ясно. Ну что тут сказать: "по ходу" самоочевидно происходит от "по ходу дела", ему *нечем* происходить от "похоже", так язык не работает — но вижу, что всё уже сильно запущено и горе-языковеды за дело взялись основательно. В доводе (2) не прослеживаю никакой логики, (3) опровергают "между прочим" и еще десятки подобных оборотов.

Comment: @NikolayErshov фразы *"походу, нас кинули"* и *"по ходу дела, нас кинули"* имеют совершенно разный смысл

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну уж "совершенно".

Comment: @NikolayErshov Язык существует в головах людей. Если люди видят связь между «похоже» и «по ходу», то, значит, эта связь и образует значение слова (этимологию оставим). Как писать – это, по-моему, всё равно, потому что слово всё равно нестандартное. Ни одно написание не вызовет у людей (легитимного) отторжения, а это главное.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Да, и самоочевидности (объективной; субъективная несущественна) я тоже никакой не вижу. Если же обращаться к доводам, то и ваш вариант выглядит натянуто. Без дополнительных исследований об этимологии этого выражения невозможно что-то заключить.

Comment: @Evgeniy Нет, значение образуют прецеденты употребления самого слова/выражения. Сходства тут могут направлять и прояснять, но в конечном счете смысл тут самостоятельный и новый. И нет, мой вариант происхождения наименее натянутый. Необязательно "по ходу дела", есть еще "по ходу действия", "по ходу игры" и т. п., это уже практически составной предлог. Выводить из "похоже" или даже любой формы глагола "походить" — это попытка провернуть фарш назад. Там негде возникнуть окончанию "-у", а произвольно окончания не возникают.

Comment: @NikolayErshov И рад бы согласиться, но не могу. Когда я впервые услышал это выражение, я без всякого объяснения и без всяких прецедентов понял, что имелось в виду «похоже» – просто по контексту и потому, что для меня это словообразование воспринялось почему-то как естественное (и даже красивое). Конечно, я не услышал бы его, если бы прецедентов не было. Но это уже другой вопрос. Словообразование (воспринимаемое) — не обязательно от «похоже»; может быть, просто от соединения приставки и слова, полученного из корня; но по аналогии.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Вы, возможно, просто не слышали этого выражения. Я и сам-то его слышал только от одного человека (как раз студента).

Comment: @Evgeniy Позвольте этим комментарием сдержанно восхититься. Я как раз слышал от бессчетного множества людей и сам употреблял. Оно не означает "похоже", у него гораздо более тонкий смысл. Что-то вроде: "и, кстати, есть непрямые свидетельства, что произошло нечто неожиданное и/или нежелательное".

Comment: @NikolayErshov Никаких непрямых свидетельств, по-моему. Смысл, конечно, тонкий, но ведь это всегда так. И ведь Павел Майоров тоже прав, что между «по ходу, нас кинули» и «по ходу происходящего, нас кинули» нет совсем ничего общего. «Я, по ходу, получил пятёрку» — вполне можно услышать от отличника. Никаких неожиданностей и никаких нежелательностей.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Можно проанализировать так: «по ходу вещей *можно понять*, что…» Что, в общем, объясняет, почему люди не любят писать слитно. Простое «по ходу дела» — это из совсем другой оперы.

Comment: @Evgeniy  Мне сложно было найти эту развернутую формулировку, я на ней не настаиваю, к тому же выражение сравнительно новое, каждый с ним знакомится ситуативно и оттого понимает слегка по-своему. Возможно, косвенность тут и впрямь необязательна. Но тем менее это похоже на "похоже", не правда ли? "Я, похоже, получил пятерку"? И да, конечно, с "по ходу происходящего" нет ничего общего. А вот "по ходу дела, нас кинули" как еще не слэнг, но уже речевой маньеризм — мне кажется вполне возможным.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53852/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-nikolay-ershov).

Comment: @Evgeniy Я не понимаю, зачем так "анализировать". "По ходу вещей можно понять, что..." — так никто никогда не говорил, чтобы потом это могло сократиться. Повторяю, мне кажется, это было "по ходу дела", используемое как речевая виньетка слегка за пределами своего нормативного смысла (так же, как и "типа"), а потом "дела" оказалось в семантически слабой позиции и отпало.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Ну так и «по ходу дела» никто никогда так не говорил, чтобы могло сократиться до «по ходу». I did reply in chat.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the modern Russian vernacular, “*по ходу*” is used instead of “*похоже*” to mean “*probably*”. That's a new phenomenon, and I think that's ugly, too. “*Похоже*” is substituted by “*по ходу*” mostly by students, both in high schools and in higher education.

=========================

В современном разговорном русском "`по ходу`" используется вместо "`похоже`" в значении "`вероятно`".  Это явление новое и, по-моему, уродливое.  "`По ходу`" вместо "`похоже`" говорят в основном школьники или студенты.

На более правильном разговорном русском (если считать "`слышь`" правильным :) ) вышеприведённые предложения звучат так:

> Слышь, сегодня лучше не попадайся на глаза шефу: он, похоже, озверел
>   из-за чего-то там.
>
> Похоже, нас кинули!

---

А ещё "по ходу" означает on the course. Пример:

```
И рвутся аорты,
Но наверх - не сметь!
Там слева по борту,
Там справа по борту,
Там прямо по ходу
Мешает проходу
Рогатая смерть!
```

(Владимир Высоцкий)

Речь идёт о гибнущей подводной лодке, которая не может всплыть, потому что на поверхности слишком много мин.

---

Наконец, "`по ходу`" может означать "в процессе, во время осуществления чего-либо" (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83) Чаще всего употребляется "`по ходу дела`".  Examples:

> И Райкин стал повсюду искать духи с этим запахом, по ходу дела
>   приобретая другие понравившиеся ароматы или просто изысканные флаконы.

-

> В общем, я решил, что сориентируюсь по ходу дела ― и был прав.

Comment: I think, an English version of this answer could be helpful.

Comment: I'm surprised this is the most upvoted answer - this has nothing to do with what the question, it's just wrong. "По ходу, на скинули" is completely different from "сориентируюсь по ходу дела".

Comment: `"По ходу, на скинули" is completely different from "сориентируюсь по ходу дела".` - first, `нас кинули`, not "на скинули".  Second, yes, they are completely different, so?  How this contradicts to anything I wrote?

Comment: Это явление уже лет пятнадцать как новое.

Comment: @bipll - пятнадцать лет - это и есть новое.

Comment: @shabunc That concerns only the lower part. The upper part contains *the* right answer. I translated it in English. By the way, in my ears that substitution is rather nice, though absolutely non-etymological. I never say it myself, though.

Answer (score 11):

It's a filler word.

Its meaning is "along the way", but it's used as a variation of *похоже* which means "like" or "it seems".

> Слышь, сегодня лучше не попадайся на глаза шефу: он, по ходу, озверел из-за чего-то там.
>
> Yo, don't let the boss get his eye on you today, he's kinda freaking out because of some shit

Answer (score 4):

Phrase "*по ходу*" here is a **parasite word**, similar to "***like***" or "***I mean***" in modern times.

> Listen, today you better hide from the boss' eyes: he, **like**, went berserk because of something there.
>
> **I mean**, we're thrown!

(not sure about this one, "**нас [про]кинули**" used to be more common, I've not heard "***нам* кинули**").

In language proper, those two words are a part of "по х**о**ду д**е**ла", which literally means "*along the way of business/lawsuit*".

Answer (score 4):

Depends on context. Might mean "Feels like..." or "Way of things"(expression that means "we'll see how it will be going")

In general, russian language can be tricky with every expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate it into correct Russian as «*кажется*»: «*мы по ходу не сдали эту лабораторную*» = «*кажется, мы не сдали эту лабораторную*» (“*I think we didn't pass this assignment*”). This strategy works very nicely for your examples, too: «*он, кажется, озверел из-за чего-то там*», «*кажется, нас кинули*» are exact matches.

Comment: @CocoPop It's not the correct sense, though.

Comment: Oh it isn't? So what is the correct sense? Could you add your own answer?

Comment: @NikolayErshov The truth is, there is no “correct” sense, because the phrase is not normal. I encountered it (very often, but from the same person) only in this sense, and the usage was very like in the question. «Похоже», «кажется», and so on; absolutely nothing to do with “по ходу дела” or anything. Other people did, too, including the author of the top answer. I replied in chat, though.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Я, кажется, догадался, что вы имели в виду что-то вроде «между прочим», даже «помимо прочего». По-моему, это исключено: в контекст этот смысл никак не вписывается, тогда как тот, что слышал я, в контекст вписывается прекрасно. Предполагать, что это какие-то «виньетки», не имеющие смысла, — это изображать людей глупее, чем они есть; так я думаю. Я-то лично в вашем смысле этого выражения никогда не слышал. Но могу поверить, что это где-то может быть.

Answer (score 1):

...он, по ходу, озверел из-за чего-то там.
...he seems to be furious at something.

По ходу, нас кинули!
It looks like we got scammed!